# Losing Session variables issue during navigation on Http and Https pages

Tags: asp.net

I am losing Session variables in our ASP.NET website when a site user navigates through HTTP and HTTPS pages.

How can I prevent this problem?

Comment: You'll need to post some code examples of where this is happening for anyone here to really help you.

Comment: Is the session being lost after a redirect?

Answer (score 2):

I can give you some generic advice on this, as it's a common problem.

For anything that must persist longer than a simple redirect (meaning, over multiple HTTP requests) use cookies instead of Session.

Session is a really bad design choice for any data that is long-living (like authentication data, etc).

Comment: Care to elaborate the downvote? My suggestion is perfectly fit to the question.